# An integral $\int_0^\pi \cos (xt) \sin tdt$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$I=\int_0^\pi \cos (xt) \sin tdt.$$

There are two method is calculating it, first, 
$$\int_0^\pi \cos(xt) \sin tdt=\frac{1}{2}(\sin (x+1)t-\sin(x-1)t))|_{t=0}^{t=\pi}=0.$$ 
While I could do it just by integrating by parts,
$$I=-\int_0^\pi \cos (xt)d \cos t\\
=-(-\cos \pi x-1-x\int_0^\pi \sin (xt)\cos tdt)\\
=1+\cos \pi x+x\int_0^\pi \sin (xt) d\sin t\\
=1+\cos \pi x-x^2I$$ 
This leads to

$$I=(1+\cos \pi x)/(1-x^2)...$$
Which one is correct??

Comment: The lack of parentheses at the top made me want to suggest $\cos x\int t\sin t\text dt$ would be appropriate as $\cos x$ would be constant inside that integral...

Comment: When you did it the first way, you screwed up: you wrote out an alternate formula for the integrand and then *forgot* to integrate it!

Comment: @KCd Please convert your comment to an answer.